# Typescript (3.8+), what are the downsides of #private fields?

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript 3.8 supports the `#private` fields. I'm used to the TypeScript's `private` fields to prevent access to these fields.

I know that these fields are **not really private** on the generated JavaScript, and the new `#private` **is private** in the generated code.

Putting the "real private" vs "fake private" aside, Is there a reason for me not to convert all my `private` to `#private`?
What are the downsides of this move? is it slower? 
Is the generated code supported by all browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a reason for me not to convert all my private to #private?

If you have to support non ES6 browsers.

> What are the downsides of this move? Is the generated code supported by all browsers?

Major downside / browser support: It is only supported by ES6 browsers

> is it slower?

It is. But be careful of premature performance optimization.

## Advantage : Hard privacy

The unasked question is why would you do it. The old keyword `private` was only a compile time thing. The new `#` private is truly private:

```
class C {
    #foo = 10;
}

const c = new C();        
console.log(new C()["#foo"]); // prints undefined as its private
```